# maven to eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, maven

I am trying to use m2e ie maven plugin for eclipse. but below site is not working.

[m2e](http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/)

Please let me know if there is any alternative solution for this. even googling too didnot help me.

Also let me know if there is any other better plugin than this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Indigo you can use the build in installer(Help -> Install new software) and use:
Indigo - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo

Then search for m2e and install it.

Comment: i am using europa, anything for this?

Comment: You could try http://download.eclipse.org/releases/europa/ Don't know if m2e is available in there.

Comment: thanks http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/sites/m2e/0.10.0.20100209-0800/    this URL finds repository.